# Python - Need a function that takes few seconds to run to test multiprocessing

Tags: python

Silly question...

I want to try out multiprocessing.

I would like to just test a basic test doing

```
for x in range(10):
    p = Process(target=func, args=(100))
    p.Daemon = True
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

I am looking for a `func` function that takes a few second to run, so that i can check the basics are working. Ideally it would be CPU heavy too so i can chek with `htop` that it is really using multiple processors.

I tried the factorial

```
def func(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
```

but i cannot having do more than a 1000 recursion , which is  not taking long enough.

Any idea of a simple function taking like 5s to run that I could use to do a simple multiprocessor test?

Comment: Just use `time.sleep()`. Also why are you creating a daemon process then trying to join it? Daemon processes are supposed to just go off and do their own thing and never be joined. Another thing, be careful here `args=(100)`, you aren't passing a tuple, just the value 100. To pass a one value tuple use `args=(100,)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it in so many ways... for example you can write to a file repeatedly in a loop

```
import time

start = time.time()
for x in range (30000):
    file = open("testfile.txt", "w")
    file.write("Hello World" + str(x))
    file.close()

end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

This function takes up around 8 secs in my machine.

Alternatively you can sleep for a second in a loop, if you don't have to engage CPU as shown below.

```
import time
for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(1)
```

Another way is just measure time elapsed and break after required number of seconds. This method keeps CPU busy and doesn't have any side effect of having to write to disk.

```
import time

start = time.time()
while True:
    t = time.time() - start
    if t > 5:
        break
```